# jquery how to use Prefix word to search selector text?

Tags: jquery, search, text, selector

Hello~ I have a input box and a selector like this:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">apple</option>
    <option value="2">box</option>
    <option value="3">table</option>
    <option value="4">swim</option>
</select>
```

I want to when I type only s and the swim will be selected automatically

I try to use this

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var cc = $('#search').val();
    $('#test option[text^=' + cc + ']:first').attr('selected', true);
});
```

but it doesn't work..... Can anyone help me?  thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dg3qs/1/

Comment: thank you! Your answer do work~!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    $('#test option:contains("' + this.value + '"):first').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dg3qs)

Answer (score 0):

use **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var cc = $('#search').val();
    $('#test option:contains("'+cc+'"):first').attr('selected', true);
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LArBW/60/)**

Comment: thank you~~ but in your demo  when I type s It doesn't work...~~

Comment: type "s" then come swim seleted its works for me and for all cases i tried in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Can use following..

```
   $('#search').keyup(function () {
       $('#test option:contains("' + this.value + '"):first').attr('selected', true);
   });
```